# A connection to api2.miktex.org could not be established

Tags: miktex, installing

I ran Miktex [Net Installer](https://miktex.org/download), chose *Download Miktex*
[image] 
then clicked *Next*, chose *complete* and then the following popped up
[image] 
I have not been able to fix this up to now, so I cannot use [Net Installer](https://miktex.org/download).

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. You seem have some connection issues with the server, maybe trying a bit later. Or else try to change connection settings. Sometimes the main server is down for a short time.

Comment: I tried to change the connection settings but realised I have no idea. Where can I find relevant information? Also: Is there any other webpage form which I can download a complete version of Miktex?

Comment: You could try to download the portable version of `miktex` but really these connection issues are often of short duration

Answer (score 1):

In my case I could fix the problem using a different wi-fi connection instead of the wire internet of my university, something related with a proxy. Then a list of servers appears and you click one of them (I chose the first one).  Now I'm downloading the complete installation. Hope finally my errors with MikTex and Texmaker be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I couldn't install any package. Then I uninstalled Miktex distribution, then I disabled my Firewall for 15 min. I reinstalled Miktex again and installed all missing packages. I enabled Firewall again. Now I can compile everything works really fine.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Disabling the firewall and fetching files from the internet is a dangerous thing, you can catch viruses. Better download miktex, disable internet connection, disable firewall, install miktex with downloaded files, activate firewall, activate internet connection ...

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to the '**Updates**' tab, proceed to '**Change Package Repository**' , and then click on '**Connection Settings**' Disable the proxy server, and this will resolve the issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Which updates tab do you mean? Can you please explain better?

Answer (score 0):

I found this thread when I had the same error when trying to compile my LaTex doc. Package installer popped up with this error because required file could not be found. Followed to change the repository, unmarked the proxy, chose a local area, and then it let me install everything I needed.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!